# Mysql Comparison LIKE function with variables that begin with numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, search, comparison

I'm working on the search functionality of a website and I want the user to be able to search for keywords. Everything works, except when the user enters "90s" it changes from "b.Name LIKE '%90s%'" to "b.Name LIKE 's%'". why is it doing that? And what can I do to force it to search for the entire query?

Comment: Sounds like you might be HTML encoding or URL encoding your query string?  Seems kinda odd, but %90 would mean space `' '`.

Comment: My guess is that it’s not the SQL engine that’s doing it. The “%90” is taken as an ascii character like it would be if you had “%90” in an URL. You may need to escape the % sign but how would depend on which piece of software is screwing you up.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that there is URL decoding somewhere along the way. If that is the case, you have to URL encode the string. Since %90 is an unassigned character, it wouldn't decode to anything.  You can try searching for '%2590' and see if that goes through as %90 to test. If that is the case, you would have to encode the string before it gets decoded.